# Copy parquet files then query them with Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I use aws-data-wrangler (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) to process pandas dataframes. Once they are processed, I export them to parquet files with:

```
wr.pandas.to_parquet(
    dataframe=my_dataframe,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    columns_comments=COLUMN_COMMENTS,
    parameters=DATASET_TAGS,
    database=my_database,
    table=f"{table}_{latest_refresh_date}",
    path=f"s3://{bucket_out}/{sub_path}/{latest_refresh_date}/",
    procs_cpu_bound=1,
    partition_cols=["date"],
    mode="overwrite_partitions",
    preserve_index=False,
)
```

By doing it this way, it also creates a Glue table. The parquet files happily live in a S3 bucket, and I can query the data with Athena using the name of the Glue table, like this:

```
select * from {table}_{latest_refresh_date}
```

Now let's say that I get new data. The new data should be stored in a new S3 path: `s3://{bucket_out}/{sub_path}/{other_refresh_date}/` for example. I process the new data as before, but I don't want to re-process the old data. So I copy the parquet files from the old path to the new one, with a simple S3 copy. The old data isn't handled with `wr.pandas.to_parquet`.

Now when I want to query the data living in `s3://{bucket_out}/{sub_path}/{other_refresh_date}/`, I can only access the new data.

```
select * from {table}_{other_refresh_date}
```

It seems I can only query the data that was added to the Glue table. I naively thought that Athena would query a S3 path but apparently it's more complicated than that.

Could you explain to me why this is happening, and maybe suggest a work around? Do I need to somehow register the old files to the new Athena table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the details of what Pandas is doing under the hood I suspect the issue is that it's creating a partitioned table (as suggested by the `partition_cols=["date"]` part of the command). A partitioned table doesn't just have one location, it has one location per partition.

This is probably what is going on: when you create the first table you end up with data on S3 looking something like this: `s3://example/table1/date=20200317/file.parquet`, and a partitioned table with a partition with a location `s3://example/table1/date=20200317/`. The table may have a location too, and it's probably `s3://example/table1/`, but this is mostly meaningless – it's not used for anything, it's just that Glue requires tables to have a location.

When you create the next table you get data in say `s3://example/table2/date=20200318/file.parquet`, and a table with a corresponding partition. What I assume you do next is copy the data from the first table to `s3://example/table2/date=20200317/file.parquet` (`table1` -> `table2` is the difference).

When you query the new table it will not look in this location, because it is not a location belonging to any of its partitions.

You can fix this in a number of ways:

- Perhaps you don't need the partitioning at all, what happens if you remove the `partition_cols=["date"]` part of the command? Do you still get a partitioned table? (check in the Glue console, or by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableX` in Athena). With an unpartitioned table you can move whatever data you want into the table's location and it will be found by Athena.
- Instead of moving the data you can add the partition from the first table to the new table, run something like this in Athena: `ALTER TABLE table2 ADD PARTITION ("date" = '20200317') LOCATION 's3://example/table1/date=20200317/'`.
- Instead add the partition to the old table, or both. It doesn't really matter and just depends on which name you want to use when you run queries. You could also have a table that you've set up manually that is your master table, and treat the tables created by Pandas as temporary. Once Pandas has created the data you add it as a partition to the master table and drop the newly created table. That way you can have a nice name for your table and not have a datestamp in the name.
- You can copy the data if you want the data to be all in one place, and then add the partition like above.
- Someone will probably suggest copying the data like above and then run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` afterwards. That works, but it will get slower and slower as you get more partitions so it's not a scalable solution.

Comment: You are right. Actually the "problem" comes from the partitioning. With partitioning, I need to repair the table to register the data. If I drop partitioning, then Athena can query the new data out of the box. Thanks.